# Text reflow in Android Webview

Tags: android, webview, zooming, reflow

Text reflow has been removed from Webviews since the Android KitKat release. Unfortunately, Lollipop does not fix the problem. It seems that, for some unknown reason, Google has decided that text reflow is not needed:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62378

I am using Webviews to show HTML code produced by my application. So I have full control over both the HTML content and the Android application. Do you know of a way to implement text reflow after pinch-zoom by the user? Perhaps it can be done by modifying the HTML or using Javascript and/or CSS? After searching the web for a few days and trying some of the proposed solutions, nothing seems to work correctly.

Alternatively, is there a different control which supports both pinch-zoom and some basic text formatting (color, bold, size, etc)?

Finally, does anyone know why Google removed pinch-zoom text reflow? It worked perfectly on Android 2.2.